# What can I do when I get a "cannot be resolved to a type" error?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a button on the `mainActivity`.  Once clicked, it takes a user to a second view.  However I keep getting an error saying that

> onclick listener cannot be resolved to a type

and

> the method set onclicklistener in the type view is not applicaible for the type of arguments

Below is the screenshot of the code:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just copy/paste your code here? Is that too hard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because your source file is still missing the required imports for the classes you want to use.

You can always auto-add missing imports using Eclipse:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

That way you don't have to guess which package you need to import.

Answer (score 3):

Use class name you may have mistaken using xml name ...
For example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this, Third.class));
}
```

You may have used "third.class"

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this, third.class));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import this

Comment: Hi thank you.  That has worked.  However the button doesn't seem to appear when I run it on the AVD.  The application runs, I just later decided to implement a button on the main activity which doesn't show up?

Comment: @Superunknown I guess that's a different matter and should belong in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.insertionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){});
```

and yes also import the above mentioned classes or press ctrl+shift+o